# Why is the tag SQLPL on SO deleted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I asked some questions about the programming language [SQL PL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_PL). It's an IBM database programming language. I'm wondering why this tag always gets deleted upon creation and what I'm doing wrong.

Most programming languages have their tag so that one can search for it.

I don't really understand why [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) (Microsoft Transact SQL) and [plsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plsql) (Oracle Procedural Programming / SQL) languages are ok and the db2 dialect is not?

Is it banned/forbidden or something? If there is something wrong with creating tags for languages then the other two should be deleted as well (wouldn't make sense to me though).

The [guides](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) tell that it shows ups on the mod tools and it would be deleted of noone else uses it.

Searching SO for [[db2] "sql pl"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[db2]+%22sql+pl%22) shows some othe questions regarding that language as well.

The first time it was deleted was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11902629/revisions). It doesn't seem to matter though if I create [sql-pl] or [[sqlpl]](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13066545/revisions); both get deleted.

Comment: Well, the particular user deleting that tag in the one example you show does state in his profile *"I'm a proud member of the New Tag Deletionist Cabal."*...so there you go I guess.

Comment: I put the tag back into your questions. Let me know if he removes them again.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Thanks.

Comment: Tip: a tag is much less likely to be deleted if it has a wiki (or at least an excerpt). I added a micro excerpt, please feel free to make a better one and suggest a proper wiki :)

Comment: Wiki + multiple questions *that aren't yours* tagged == enough to stop the Cabal.  I actually nuked the tag there because there wasn't enough proof that "SQL PL" was a thing and the tag seemed unnecessary in the face of the less specific db2 tag.